# Copy files from Terminal command line result

Tags: macos, terminal

With the `find`-command in OS X Terminal. The files and folders I'm getting I would like to copy to another folder. The problem is that files are after copying outside of their folder. The command line is

```
find ~/Library/Safari -exec cp -R {} ~/Music/ \;
```

Has anyone another solution?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: The paths of the Safari-Library and the Music-Folder are only examples.

Comment: Please refer to the following link for information regarding the [OSX Terminal](http://furbo.org/2014/09/03/the-terminal/)

Comment: I didn't found there the solution of my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *"they are outside their folder"*?

Comment: Your `find` command is hitting both the files and the directories within `~/Library/Safari`. Each is copied to `~/Music/`. When the files are copied, they end up immediately inside `~/Music`. When the directories are copied, though, you're copying them recursively. So, you're copying every file and every directory, even if they were already copied as part of a parent directory. You're exploding the number of files and directories. You need to better explain what you're trying to achieve. Do you want just the files, in a flat organization? Do you want the top-level directories?

Comment: For example: I have two folders. In this to folders are in each case two files and one folder. After copying I have four empty folders and four files in `~/Music`